# In XS, how do I get a variables address from its name?

Tags: perl, xs

In XS, how do I turn a string that holds a variable name into its address, I want to do something like the following perl code:

```
our $var = 1;
print ${$main::{var}};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [perlguts](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlguts), it says:

> If you know the name of a scalar variable, you can get a pointer to its SV by using the following:
>
> ```
> SV*  get_sv("package::varname", FALSE);
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I was too lazy to look for it.

Comment: No problem. I'm not an RTFM-type of guy.